# How do I present data from a text file to CrossTable in R?

Tags: r, import, importerror

I am having trouble importing data to R so that the CrossTable package will do a simple chi squared test. Thank you for any tips on how to import the data in the correct way: the test is fine when I enter data manually but not when I import into a table - see below. /OT

```
> library(gmodels)
> library(MASS)

> #When I enter the data manually there's no problem running a simple chi-squared:
> CA<-c(42,100,10,5)
> noCA<-c(20,0,140,40)
> regionalca<-cbind(CA,noCA)
> regionalca
      CA noCA
[1,]  42   20
[2,] 100    0
[3,]  10  140
[4,]   5   40
> CrossTable(regionalca, fisher=FALSE, chisq=TRUE, expected=TRUE, , sresid=TRUE, format="SPSS")

   Cell Contents
|-------------------------|
|                   Count |
|         Expected Values |
| Chi-square contribution |
|             Row Percent |
|          Column Percent |
|           Total Percent |
|            Std Residual |
|-------------------------|

Total Observations in Table:  357 

             |  
             |       CA  |     noCA  | Row Total | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
        [1,] |       42  |       20  |       62  | 
             |   27.266  |   34.734  |           | 
             |    7.962  |    6.250  |           | 
             |   67.742% |   32.258% |   17.367% | 
             |   26.752% |   10.000% |           | 
             |   11.765% |    5.602% |           | 
             |    2.822  |   -2.500  |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
        [2,] |      100  |        0  |      100  | 
             |   43.978  |   56.022  |           | 
             |   71.366  |   56.022  |           | 
             |  100.000% |    0.000% |   28.011% | 
             |   63.694% |    0.000% |           | 
             |   28.011% |    0.000% |           | 
             |    8.448  |   -7.485  |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
        [3,] |       10  |      140  |      150  | 
             |   65.966  |   84.034  |           | 
             |   47.482  |   37.274  |           | 
             |    6.667% |   93.333% |   42.017% | 
             |    6.369% |   70.000% |           | 
             |    2.801% |   39.216% |           | 
             |   -6.891  |    6.105  |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
        [4,] |        5  |       40  |       45  | 
             |   19.790  |   25.210  |           | 
             |   11.053  |    8.677  |           | 
             |   11.111% |   88.889% |   12.605% | 
             |    3.185% |   20.000% |           | 
             |    1.401% |   11.204% |           | 
             |   -3.325  |    2.946  |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
Column Total |      157  |      200  |      357  | 
             |   43.978% |   56.022% |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|


Statistics for All Table Factors


Pearson's Chi-squared test 
------------------------------------------------------------
Chi^2 =  246.0862     d.f. =  3     p =  4.595069e-53 



       Minimum expected frequency: 19.78992 

> #But when I try to import the data from a .txt file, it becomes unacceptable:

> regionalca<-read.table(file="låtsas ca.txt", header=TRUE)
> regionalca
   CA noCA
1  43   20
2 100    1
3  10  140
4   5   40
> CrossTable(regionalca, fisher=FALSE, chisq=TRUE, expected=TRUE, , sresid=TRUE, format="SPSS")
Error in margin.table(x, margin) : 'x' is not an array
> #I would really like to run the test on this table:
> regionalca<-read.table(file="låtsas ca.txt", header=TRUE)
> regionalca
     region  CA noCA
1     south  43   20
2 southwest 100    0
3       mid  10  140
4     north   5   40
> #Which ob
> CrossTable(regionalca, fisher=FALSE, chisq=TRUE, expected=TRUE, , sresid=TRUE, format="SPSS")
Error in if (any(x < 0) || any(is.na(x))) stop("all entries of x must be nonnegative and finite") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘<’ not meaningful for factors
>
```

Comment: There is no CrossTable package. Have you read the help page for whatever function this is? Does it say that the first argument can be a dataframe? `CrossTable {gmodels}` says it expects the first argument to be a vector or a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The error is very explicit :

```
if (any(x < 0) || any(is.na(x))) 
 stop("all entries of x must be nonnegative and finite")
```

You have not eligible inputs for `CrossTable` ( `gmodels` package). I can reproduce it using your data and introduction a non negative value:

```
 CA  <- c(-1,100,10,5)   ## -1 the first value
```

So you need to remove all this values before or setting them by another value. For example :

```
regionalca <-  regionalca[rowSums(!regionalca < 0) == ncol(regionalca) & 
                          rowSums(!is.na(regionalca))==ncol(regionalca),]
```

Answer (score 0):

The probelm is that the read.table create a data.frame, yet what you need is a matrix. Note the sing `c.bind()` defaulting in a matrix class output. It is also specified in the error you have printed:
`Error in margin.table(x, margin) : 'x' is not an array`, while array equals matrix, in that case.
That is in order to fix it you need to change your code as follows:
    `regionalca<-as.matrix(read.table(file="låtsas ca.txt", header=TRUE))`

Comment: Thanks so much for the helpful reply! /OT